# Source for Lubavitch-style hat

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, clothing, chasidut-hasidism

Most Lubavitcher *chassidim*, if not all, who I see wearing fedora-style hats with a down-brim have deep pinches impressed on them (see image in link of rabbi below). What is the reason(s) for these style pinches?

This style seems to have first been worn by the last Lubavitcher Rebbe, since from pictures of other previous Lubavitcher rabbis it appears they did not wear black felt hats at all.

---

I'm looking only for demonstrably authentic sources from the "innovator" himself, [R. Schneerson](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Mendel_Schneerson). Kindly submit all other kinds of answers in the comments section.

Comment: https://w3.chabad.org/media/images/1869.jpg

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Thank you! Do you know if he's then the first? I'd like to update the q.

Comment: Side note: this hat style is known as the 'teardrop'.

Comment: @Salmononius2 I'm aware of that. It was very common throughout the 20th century, but the pinches not as much. Regardless, Lubavitchers make a point (no pun intended) to have it; religiously.

Comment: It's not the Lubavitch style hat but the Yeshivish style hat. The last Lubavitcher Rebbe insisted on ditching a lot of the old Chasidic garb which distinguished Chasidim from Litvaks and start wearing the same thing; that way the boundries would be less apparent. Another reason being that Chasidim shouldn't wear something different than the rest of the Jewish world and look like they thought they were "more holy" somehow.

Comment: @ezra "Yeshivish style hat" does not have deeply impressed pinches; Lubavitch does.

Comment: @Oliver Indeed however the hat is the same

Comment: Out of all the Rabbeim whose pictures we have, they all wore different style hats. For example, the 5th Lubavitcher Rebbe (Rashab) wore a different hat in that passport photo than the 6th Lubavitcher Rebbe. Also, they only wore the Shtreimel (or spodik) in Lubavitch. The Frierdiker Rebbe didn't wear it the whole time he was in Russia since at least 1916 until 1929 (IIRC), when he started again by the Rebbe's wedding. I think that since then he only wore it when in his "permanent residence" wherever it may be, but he definitely did wear it when he moved to Crown Heights.

Comment: Chabad Chassidim generally didn't wear Shtreimels for a while. By the time of the 6th Lubavitcher Rebbe it was quite rare.

Comment: http://chabadtalk.com/forum/showthread.php3?t=1525

Comment: @ezra R u sure that Rav Menachem Mendel didn't make a business deal with Borsalino?

Comment: @DanF Is that a joke? Yes I am sure that was not the case. The people who made the Rebbes hat are called Ben Craft Hatters, they sell Borsalinos but aren't a Borsalino company

Comment: @ezra Even if DanF is joking, it's very possible Bosalino kept much of the Borsalino styles for their largest consumer - Bencraft.

Comment: @ezra LOL  [] :-{=